# Emigrating while investing

Tags: investing

If I have invested using a mobile app, like eToro, Trading212, BUX etc and then I decide to live abroad (permanently) would I have  to close all my invested positions/accounts and start from scratch in my new country of residence?

Specifically from the U.K. to Poland while using Etoro.

Comment: Would likely depend on (a) the laws of the country where you are, (b) the laws of the country you emigrate to, and (c) the Ts&Cs of the platform you're using. As such, I fear it's far too broad a question.

Comment: Of course, thanks - updated question.